# Ettercap arp poisoning doesn't work correctely, it doesn't receive packet

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, security

I'have installed a ettercap IU in my ubuntu 16.04 and I tried to sniff my virtual machine,but no packet was received.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you in fact running Xubuntu rather than plain Ubuntu?  If you are running Xubuntu you're running a version that is **not supported** as Xubuntu's Long Term Support term is only *three years* instead of Ubuntu's longer term.  Questions about unsupported versions of Ubuntu and its flavours are off-topic here.

Comment: @StephenMichaelKellat, Thanks for your replay, I think that ettercap doesn't sniff  my virtual machine, but it sniffed all host in my local network.

Answer (score 0):

The usual mechanism for packet sniffers is to set a specific interface into promiscuous mode. Virtual machines usually get their own ethernet bridge or tun/tap interface, depending upon the virtualization tool in use, settings, etc.

You may need to select a different interface in the ettercap capture settings.